# Play Framework 2.5 serve node_modules files

Tags: playframework

I want to serve node_modules files in my play app.

But.. when i did it like this:

*routes*

```
GET     /assets/*file                   controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
GET     /node_modules/*file             controllers.Assets.at(path="/node_modules", file)
```

and in a browser i typed http://localhost:9000/node_modules/angular2/animate.js

i get error page.

Here is response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 5704
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 20 Mar 2016 13:35:58 GMT
```

For request

```
GET /node_modules/angular2/animate.js HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.37 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

In previous versions of play we could tell play to look at a new folder as assets folder via:

playAssetsDirectories <+= baseDirectory / "node_modules"

but it's not available anymore:(

Comment: Shouldn't `path="node_modules"` be `path="/node_modules"`?

Comment: Good point, still it does't work:(

Comment: The `node_modules` directory should be placed right next to `public` and not inside it, correct?

Comment: correct, it's directory created by npm

Comment: Maybe this helps https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration23#sbt-web

Comment: I removed sbt-web plugin, it made me go through alot of pain. It doesn't combine well with native npm which i use as part of design.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to mess with the assets/routing mechanism in Play, there is one easy way to achieve this. Here I am assuming that your `node_modules` directory is placed next to the `public` directory.

What you create is just another controller which will take care of the extra assets:

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.*;
import java.io.File;

public class NodeModulesController extends Controller {

    public Result at(String filePath) {
        File file = new File("node_modules/" + filePath);
        return ok(file, true);
    }
}
```

In the `routes` file you can use the newly created controller like this:

```
GET     /node_modules/*file         controllers.NodeModulesController.at(file)
```

**Bonus:** do you see the `true` parameter when calling the `ok()` method? This tells if the file should be *inlined* (true) or send as *attachment* (false). So if you are building some directory with Node modules and you want your users to *view* or *download* the files, you can just flip the parameter (assuming that file attachment is handled by the browser properly and it displays a 'do-you-want-to-download-this-file' prompt).

Comment: I implemented your proposition in scala and it works! It feels a little dirty still it's better then broken app:)
Any ideas why standard Assets didn't work?

Comment: TBH I am not entirely sure as I haven't tried this use case with 2.5.x yet. However in SBT you can define a directory for additional resources (http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html#Add+an+additional+resource+directory). This on other hand means that something like `unmanagedResourceDirectories in Assets += baseDirectory.value / "node_modules"` in your `build.sbt` *should* work :)